# how to expand an HTML5 video to touch left/right edges?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, html5-video

I was able to insert an HTML5 video and make it responsive (width="100%"). However, I want to make it touching both edges just like this website: https://www.clinkle.com/team

How can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if it doesn't "touch both edges" then probably you have padding and margins in your parents element, try putting margin:0px ; padding: 0px; in body and html or maybe using some reset css available somewhere.

Anyway that video is a width:100% and height:100%; in a container with fixed width and height calculated via javascript depending on the browser size.

Comment: Yeah, removing margin and padding on the parent elements will do the job. Starting from the `html` and `body` selectors.